# Time travel only possible when we go behond light's speed

Tags: space-travel, time-travel, spacetime-dimensions

Friends here are my views on Time Travel:

I think with every past second the light rays of that particular second travel in a different dimension & therefore the light rays of next second travels behind the previous second light rays (as speed of light is const. therefore a diff. is maintain b/w the two light rays of different time)

So if we need to catch past time light rays then we need to travel at a very high speed than light rays to grab the ancient days light rays (which is in an unknown dimension).

So do you really thing that this can be a scenario to travel past in time?

Comment: This isn't a question. Nothing is asked here.

Comment: Edited now it can be answered right!

Comment: Time travel and beign faster than light are just fiction. Currently it is believed that these things are impossible. Therefore it is up to you: if you want it to be this way than just explain it to your audience. "Sanderson’s First Law of Magics: An author’s ability to solve conflict with magic is DIRECTLY PROPORTIONAL to how well the reader understands said magic". This is not different from magic. I am also wondering: Is this really about world-building? Please visit the [help center](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help) to learn about writing questions

Comment: I think I almost get what you're asking, but you need to read up on the concept of the [light cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_cone) and see if you can clarify a little more.

Comment: Assuming Special Relativity holds, and we have absolutely no reason to think it doesn't, faster-than-light travel is equivalent to time travel.  If we have one, we have the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Nope

To explain, let's assume that you're travelling along a straight line, which we'll define to be the $x$-axis. The Earth (or wherever you're travelling from) has frame $S$ and you have frame $S'$. You leave at time $t_1 = t'_1$ at position $x_1 = x'_1$, arrive at position $x_2$ and time $t_2$ according to frame $S$ and $x'_2 = x'_1$ and $t'_2$ in $S'$ (in your own frame, you're stationary, so arrive at the same point you left off). I'm assuming that you can instantaneously accelerate to whatever speed for simplicity.

This gives $\Delta x' = x'_2 - x'_1 = 0$, so rather conveniently, $\Delta t = \gamma \Delta t'$ and $\Delta x = \gamma v \Delta t'$ where $\Delta t'$ is the time that you've been travelling for (in your own frame - this is always positive or $0$) and $$\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$

Now, you're (somehow) able to travel faster than light, so $v>c$. Unsurprisingly, this gives $v^2 > c^2$, so $\gamma$ is *imaginary*. This means that you've travelled an imaginary time according to frame $S$. You've simply arrived before a light signal could have - you haven't actually travelled back in time.

**Trying a different tactic** You want a negative $\Delta t$, so you want $\gamma < 0$ (remember, $\Delta t' \geq 0$). Unfortunately, a quick plot on Wolfram Alpha shows that [this is impossible](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2Fsqrt(1-b%5E2)) (I've used $b=\frac{v}{c}$). However, a similar effect to the above is possible if you have an imaginary velocity - you arrive before a light signal sent at the same time as you leaving.

**In other words**, there's no way to travel faster than light regardless of what velocity you have - you need a different method.

Comment: This does fit for normal matter in a vacuum. However if we change one of those things it is possible to over take the light. [Čerenkov radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherenkov_radiation) is evidence of normal(charged) matter over taking light rays in some medium other than a vacuum (it is impossible in a vacuum). Tachyons are still only a theory but they, supposedly, always travel backwards in time due to their imaginary mass (weird, right?). However, getting a person to experience these is rather more difficult.

Comment: @LioElbammalf Sorry, I wasn't clear enough - here, $c$ just happens to be the speed of light in a vacuum, but is actually the universal speed limit (the equations are just standard special relativity equations), although yes, it is possible to travel faster than light in something other than a vacuum. In modern-day physics, a tachyon is a particle with an imaginary mass, which is just related to the decay time of the particle and so, they don't actually travel back in time

Comment: Ah, yes, I had interpreted the imaginary time $\tau=t \sqrt{1-\frac{v^{2}}{c^{2}}} \rightarrow \tau \propto i t$ as moving backwards in time where there is nothing to suggest this is the case. The imaginary mass is just to make sure it doesn't also have imaginary energy and momentum I assume.

Comment: @LioElbammalf What I've gathered is this: say a 2 level quantum system evolves with time as $e^{-i\omega_1 t}|g> + e^{-i\omega_2 t}|e>$ where $\omega \propto E$. So, if you want decay, you want something like $e^{-i\omega ' t - \Gamma t} = e^{i\omega t}$. In other words $E \propto \omega = \omega ' - i\Gamma$ now has an imaginary component directly related to the decay time, giving an imaginary component to 'mass'. It gets really weird when you start asking about how fast a tunnelling particle travels, when imaginary velocities may or may not creep in, depending on your viewpoint